# Subspaces of $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have defined a subspace of $R^2$ as $y=2x$ because it is the only option that is a subspace that is not $R^2$ itself, or the zero vector, which is a trivial subspace because it only has one element (0).

How would I write this subspace ($y=2x$) in set notation?

How would I write some of the specific vectors in this subspace?

How would I write some of the specific vectors that are not in this subspace?

Finally, how would I represent arbitrary vectors in this subspace?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

1) Not only $y = 2x$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$, but all lines that pass through the origin.

2) $y = 2x$ can be written as $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|y = 2x\}$

Or, alternatively, as Oiler mentioned, we can also write this as $\{(x,2x) \in \mathbb{R^2}|x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

3) An element of this subspace is for example $(1,2)$

4) An element that is not in this subspace is for example $(1,1)$. In fact, the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|y \neq 2x\}$ defines the set of all vectors that are not in this subspace.

5) An arbitrary vector can be denoted as $(x_0,2x_0)$

Comment: Didn't think it was worth writing as a separate answer, but one could also have $\{ (x, 2x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: Of course, will edit and give credit.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This was so helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. If an answer helped you, you can always accept it so other users know your question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

$$W=\{(x,y):x,y \in\mathbb{R},y=2x\}$$
$$W=\{(x,y):x,y \in\mathbb{R},y\neq2x\}$$
$$W=\{c(1,2): c \in \mathbb{R}\}$$